# C++ writing random function and parameter

Tags: c++, function, random, parameters

can someone write the whole code modified for me please? i modify my own but still there is error , i want to use function and call it into printing main
    #include  
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
int addition(int a=(rand()%99),int b=(rand()%99) {
    int r;
    r=a+b;
    return r;
}

int main() {
   int print, a, b;
 print = addition(a, b);
 cout << "this is result of addition" << print;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here:

First, you do not call `srand`, which is necessary to set up a random seed (normally via `srand(time(nullptr)`).

Secondly, the line `print= int addition(int a,int b);` is written incorrectly. Assuming you want to use the default arguments, it should be `print = addition();`, as you are not declaring the function, but calling it.

This would make the main function like this:

```
int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));
    int print;
    print= int addition();
    cout<<"this is result of addition"<<print;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** This is assuming you actually **want** the behaviour that your function has default arguments which are random. This in itself seems like a bad design decision, and it would probably be better to send random numbers generated by the caller. This would make the resulting function:

```
int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));
    int a = rand()%99, b = rand()%99;
    int print;
    print= int addition(a, b);
    cout<<"this is result of addition"<<print;
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that rand()%99 will return a value in the range [0,98].

Comment: To those who have downvoted my answer: It is very useful if you write a comment to motivate the vote, so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
print = int addition(int a, int b);
```

is nonsense. You probably wanted:

```
print = addition();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error.. your main change in:

```
 int print, a, b;
 std::srand(std::time(0));
 print = addition(a, b);
 cout << "this is result of addition" << print;
```

### edit

anyway you can remove the declaration of 'a' and 'b' variables, since you does not use them in the code. In this way, you have to call addition without any parameters:

```
 print = addition();
```

Comment: This would call addition with uninitialized values for a and b, which is definitely not good. It is more likely he would want to use the default arguments.